# How to Decode Compressed Binary .RAW Files from LTspice with python

Tags: python, binary, compression, decode

I am trying to read from .raw LTSPice files. In the Control panel of LTSPice, there is a possibility to switch between ASCII and binary compression. ASCII is readable without a problem, but it has drawbacks in size and performance, and that's the reason why I want to use binary compression. There is a possibility to select 2nd order compression, and that's the target.
LTSpice gives as output .raw files, and ASCII file has values of voltages and currents, but in a binary file, there are symbols that I couldn't decode.

First I tried to open .raw files with notepad++. Notpad++ shows in the bottom left UTF-8 when I open ASCII .raw files and UCS-2 Little Endian when open binary decompressed .raw files.
I tried with different encoding such as UTF-16le, ISO-8859-1...actually I print all codecs and tried with them:

```
import codecs
print(dir(codecs))
```

Also, I tried without BOM. I found this and it gives no results for me:

```
import codecs
encoded_text = open('Circuit_binary_Transient.raw', 'rb').read()    #should read in binary mode to get the BOM correctly
bom= codecs.BOM_UTF16_LE                                      #print dir(codecs) for other encodings
assert encoded_text.startswith(bom)                           
encoded_text= encoded_text[len(bom):]                         #strip away 
decoded_text= encoded_text.decode('utf-16le')
print(decoded_text)
```

I found that Zlib is common compression and I tried to find out on which positions in my file I have compression, but whitout results.
I used:

```
import zlib
from glob import glob

def zipstreams(filename):
    """Return all zip streams and their positions in file."""
    with open(filename, 'rb') as fh:
        data = fh.read()
    i = 0
    while i < len(data):
        try:
            zo = zlib.decompressobj()
            yield i, zo.decompress(data[i:])
            i += len(data[i:]) - len(zo.unused_data)
        except zlib.error:
            i += 1

for i, data in zipstreams("Circuit_binary_Transient.raw.raw"):
    print (i, len(data))
```

I always get 0 for len(data).

I found this script, but without the implementation of binary .raw files decoding:
 http://www2.ee.unsw.edu.au/~tlehmann/ltspy.py
Also, I found the solution for Matlab, LTSpice2Matlab by Paul Wagner (ltspice reader for Matlab), but I need it for python, and from that particular script I can't find which encoding is used. I found that for binary decompressed files Paul Wagner used interpolation to get more points and then to convert to a readable format.

Actually, I used this code to read .raw files:

```
data = fo.read() # Binary data read
fo.close()
line = str(data, encoding='utf-16le')
print(line)
```

When I used ASCII .raw files and UTF8 then I have text at the end, but when I used binary compressed .raw files I cant find how to decode file in readable format.

This is what I have currently in .raw file from LTSpice (After text "Binary:"):

```
栋㲚朎㲚鸞㕼鸞㕼鸞땼䕘퇠≄뻕襾㷨⁄㷨⡜㚾⡜㚾⡜뚾䕘퇠≄㻥䏨㹔ᙘ㹓㜬㜬뜬岓逇Ⳡ㻵◲㻇㯋㻃㞟㞟랟ጟ箽㼄籼㼯덌㼩Ӏ㠋Ӏ㠋Ӏ렋괄蝄㼎ڕ㽦럍㽢먵㠹먵㠹먵령귴脍侧㼑з㽴鍰㽲럜㡆럜㡆럜롆쵺튆㼒㽺땺㽹迀㡌迀㡌迀롌偵姏䰦㼔㽾枎㽽雈㡏雈㡏雈롏䰼ᬇⅤ㼖쵅㽿ᦊ㽾⢖㡐⢖㡐⢖롐暾좳죯㼗챭㽼錒㽺䕈㡍䕈㡍䕈롍얳✀礦㼚嘻㽰㽫㿃㡁㿃㡁㿃롁먬쬥㼞㽉뙵㽁낁㠞낁㠞낁렞袨�봜㼢睿㻔瘵㻄㞠㞠랠嘈䆬흞㼦㷧븥譻븠蒱뜃蒱뜃蒱㜃빝袏噥㼪뼝뼙㼆럼㼆럼㼆㟼玵嬆㼬ﵠ뽐】뽏멬렩멬렩멬㠩떋Ҕ덭㼭葔뽩뽨챢렾챢렾챢㠾넼ꧼ㼮쏐뽵뼃뽵傴롉傴롉傴㡉뮷惵㼯툡뽻뽻婇롎婇롎婇㡎�ﶻሣ㼰姢뽿ᚶ뽿롐롐㡐誔
```

I expect to decode and read this, and I suppose that I should get the same as in ASCII .raw files, such as:

```
0       0.000000000000000e+000  
    1.884843971540818e-002  
    1.884796850054908e-002  
    9.423984250366810e-007  
    9.423984250274539e-007  
    -9.423984250328532e-007  
1       3.951925877448456e-008  
    1.959322256186405e-002  
    1.959271263253092e-002  
    9.796356316741367e-007  
    9.796356316265457e-007  
    -9.796356317259836e-007  
2       1.185577763234539e-007  
    2.108275522427772e-002  
    2.108216492289399e-002  
    1.054108246213077e-006  
    1.054108246144700e-006  
    -1.054108246245633e-006
```

I will appreciate any help. The goal is to read a compressed binary .raw LTSpice file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Notpad++ shows in the bottom left UTF-8 when I open ASCII .raw files and UCS-2 Little Endian when open binary decompressed .raw files."

This is normal, UTF-8 is a **text** encoding, it simply associates a sequence of bytes to some character. Raw binary files don't have a fixed structure or an encoding, because they contain binary data: think, for example, of the difference between the string `"3.1415926535"` (that's 12 bytes in UTF-8) and the raw float binary representation of that value (which fits in 4 bytes). If you interpret the "raw" 4 bytes of the float as text you'll either get some garbage text output or a unicode decode error.  For raw files, the specific data format ad the meaning of each byte is specified by the software that generates them.

Normally, you should look up the LTSpice raw file specification, understand how data is arranged and write yourself a parser for that. But since this is python, [someone already did that for you and made a package you can install via `pip`](https://pypi.org/project/ltspice/), look up that package and its examples, it should be pretty straightforward to use.

---

#### Update

At [this link](https://ez.analog.com/design-tools-and-calculators/f/q-a/107457/ltspice-raw-data-format) they state the raw binary format is not officially disclosed and may chane anytime (although it hasn't for the last 15 years).

The format itself is a UTF-16 header followed by raw binary data.
When you say:

> This is what I have currently in .raw file from LTSpice (After text "Binary:"): [...]

That's the raw data (decoded at UTF-16, which, as you see, is nonsense in text). That raw data is a packed list of the variable's values **in the order defined in the header**, repeating for as many time points as you have in the data. Time is encoded in **double** (i.e., 8 bytes), anything else -unless you force it to double too - is in **float** (4 bytes).
What you should do, then, is:

1) Parse the variables list and compute how long is one record (e.g., 8 + 4*num_of_variables)

2) take the byte data from the "Binary" string until the end of the file, 
 and split it in chunks of the length you get at step 1

3) interpret the bytes in the record accordingly

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have already tried with ltspice library and it didnt work for me. When I used binary compressed file as input, I got this error "line = str(tmp, encoding='UTF16')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 366-367: illegal encoding".
In that library is used utf-16le encoding to decode, but it doesnt work for my raw file. Also, if I just could find LTSpice raw file specification, that will be helpful.

Comment: https://ez.analog.com/design-tools-and-calculators/f/q-a/107457/ltspice-raw-data-format This might point you in the right direction for the file format. They say, the format is not officially disclosed, so it's unlikely you'll find a proper format documentation, but it still may help. Essentially, the raw file is a UTF-16 header plus raw binary data.

Comment: Unfortunately I have already read that :(...The header is UTF-16 and is successfuly converted and readable, but the part in .raw file after "Binary:" is converted in Chinese symbols with UTF-16...I tried a lot of things and I can't find solution :(

Comment: Thank you. I am at work, and after working time I will try this. Actually, I have already tried with hex editor and I have hex data of "Chinese symbols (UTF-16)" and I will try step by step. If I have some questions I will try to get you :)

Comment: @GPhilo-Thanks once again. I tried and everything is perfect. I left answer what I actually did.

Comment: I looked at the raw data and I see that strangely the time entry is sometimes negative do you know why that is?

Comment: Hey! I have no clue, sorry :/ I'm really not familiar with LTSpice.

Answer (score 1):

The header of the .RAW binary file from LTSpice could be decoded with UTF-16. If one tries to convert a whole binary RAW file, then only the header will be converted to text. The last characters successfully converted to text with UTF-16 are "Binary:". After this, one should get "Chinese symbols" or something else that is not readable.

I used a hex editor and compared both - RAW ASCII file and RAW binary file for the same electric circuit. In the ASCII file, one could find "Values:" instead of "Binary:", and after that decimal values. So, it is possible to compare binary code, with the help of hex editor, and real values in the RAW ASCII file.

After comparison, I successfully decoded a RAW binary file. Everything written below is in hex. I had 6 variables. This is valid for domains: DC sweep, DC op, Transient and DC Transfer (for AC analysis and Noise are always 2 x 8 Bytes Double precision decoding).

1. After "Binary:", there are always 3 bytes: 00 0A 00 (0A - Line Feed);
2. Then there are 8 bytes, which give the correct value if one converts that as Double (float64) precision;
3. Then I have 4 bytes, which give correct value if one converts that as Single(float32) precision
4. 4 bytes which give one value are repeated 5 times (I have 6 variables - header "No. Variables:")
5. Points 2., 3. and 4. are repeated until the number from header for "No. Points:" is satisfied.

I used LTSpice XVII.
Also, I used HxD Hex Editor https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/

EDIT: Very important: Byte order is Little endian!
That means for byte order in hex - AA 77 B8 A2, that it should be converted in reversed order - A2 B8 77 AA.
So, Single (float32) precision for AA 77 B8 A2 converted in decimal is -2.2e-13, and for A2 B8 77 AA converted in decimal is -5e-18.